# Is it possible to get all XML data in single dimensional array?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, xml-parsing

Example :

```
<school>
  <students>
    <student idNumber="123" enrollmentNo="E101">
      <name>
        <firstname>Jack</firstname>
        <lastname>Harmor</lastname>
        <standard>7th</standard>
      </name>
    </student>
    <student idNumber="243">
      <name>
        <firstname>Cris</firstname>
        <lastname>Warner</lastname>
        <standard>5th</standard>
      </name>
    </student>
    <student idNumber="345">
      <name>
        <firstname>Rick</firstname>
        <lastname>Corner</lastname>
        <standard>6th</standard>
      </name>
    </student>
  </students>
  <fees type="teaching">
    <fifth>100</fifth>
    <sixth>110</sixth>
    <seventh>120</seventh>
  </fees>
</school>
```

I want to create an array like below

```
array(
  [students_student_name_firstname0]=>Jack,
  [students_student_name_lastname0]=>Harmor,
  [students_student_name_standard0]=>7th,
  [students_student_name_firstname1]=>Cris,
  [students_student_name_lastname1]=>Warner,
  [students_student_name_standard1]=>5th,
  [students_student_name_firstname2]=>Rick,
  [students_student_name_lastname2]=>Corner,
  [students_student_name_standard2]=>6th,
  [students_fifth0]=>100,
  [students_sixth0]=>110,
  [students_seventh0]=>120,
  [attributes]=>array(
    [student0]=>array(
      [idNumber]=>123,
      [enrollmentNo]=>E101
    ),
    [student1]=>array(
      [idNumber]=>243
    ),
    [student2]=>array(
      [idNumber]=>345
    )
  )
);
```

Above is example that this kind of XML may be send to get data, but problem is there is any number of level of XML may be level 1,2,3,..,N so how can i get all data in single/two dimensional array as above(it means limited level of array) and what is the easiest way to store its key names and values and attribute names and its values for the particular tag dynamically? Or if you have any better way to do this then you can also share. I have no more knowledge about that so please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your expected output array a requirement in that format or did you simply want to organize the xml into an accessible array for wherever you sending it to process?

Comment: Using a flat array like this seems like it's more trouble than it's worth. I recommend `$array = json_decode( json_encode( simplexml_load_string( $xml_string ) ), true );` so that you can confidently iterate, sort, etc... without the need to perform substring checking.

Comment: Yes dmotors i am just want to organize it to easily accessible array.

Comment: MonkeyZeus it returns me DOMElement Object
(
)

Comment: No it doesn't. How are you getting your XML string?

Answer (score 1):

For a direct conversion to an array and you can handle it in a loop as you wish you can simply do:

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xml)), true);
```

However, if you want to flatten as much as possible then you can do something extra like so:

```
$xml = '
<school>
  <students>
    <student idNumber="123" enrollmentNo="E101">
      <name>
        <firstname>Jack</firstname>
        <lastname>Harmor</lastname>
        <standard>7th</standard>
      </name>
    </student>
    <student idNumber="243">
      <name>
        <firstname>Cris</firstname>
        <lastname>Warner</lastname>
        <standard>5th</standard>
      </name>
    </student>
    <student idNumber="345">
      <name>
        <firstname>Rick</firstname>
        <lastname>Corner</lastname>
        <standard>6th</standard>
      </name>
    </student>
  </students>
  <fees type="teaching">
    <fifth>100</fifth>
    <sixth>110</sixth>
    <seventh>120</seventh>
  </fees>
</school>
';

$array = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xml)), true);

$result = [];
foreach ($array['students']['student'] as $element) {
    $data = [];

    foreach ($element as $elements) {
        foreach ($elements as $k => $v) {
            $data[$k] = $v;
        }
    }

    $result[] = $data;
}

$fees = [];
foreach ($array['fees'] as $k => $v) {
    if ($k == '@attributes') {
        foreach ($v as $attr => $val) {
            $fees[$attr] = $val;
        }
    } else {
        $fees[$k] = $v;
    }
}

$result['fees'] = $fees;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idNumber] => 123
            [enrollmentNo] => E101
            [firstname] => Jack
            [lastname] => Harmor
            [standard] => 7th
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [idNumber] => 243
            [firstname] => Cris
            [lastname] => Warner
            [standard] => 5th
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [idNumber] => 345
            [firstname] => Rick
            [lastname] => Corner
            [standard] => 6th
        )

    [fees] => Array
        (
            [type] => teaching
            [fifth] => 100
            [sixth] => 110
            [seventh] => 120
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to get all of the text nodes with a value in (i.e. exclude the normal whitespace in any document) and all of the attributes, you can use the following code.  Note that this doesn't give you the same format as you give, but the format should allow you to come up with something your after..

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->load($file);
$xp = new DOMXPath($xml);
$entries = $xp->query("//node()[not(node())][string-length(normalize-space(.) ) > 1]");
foreach ( $entries as $data )   {
    echo $data->getNodePath()."=".$data->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
}

echo "Attributes".PHP_EOL;
$attributes = $xp->query("//@*");
foreach ( $attributes as $data )   {
    echo $data->getNodePath()."=".$data->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Gives...

```
/school/students/student[1]/name/firstname/text()=Jack
/school/students/student[1]/name/lastname/text()=Harmor
/school/students/student[1]/name/standard/text()=7th
/school/students/student[2]/name/firstname/text()=Cris
/school/students/student[2]/name/lastname/text()=Warner
/school/students/student[2]/name/standard/text()=5th
/school/students/student[3]/name/firstname/text()=Rick
/school/students/student[3]/name/lastname/text()=Corner
/school/students/student[3]/name/standard/text()=6th
/school/fees/fifth/text()=100
/school/fees/sixth/text()=110
/school/fees/seventh/text()=120
Attributes
/school/students/student[1]/@idNumber=123
/school/students/student[1]/@enrollmentNo=E101
/school/students/student[2]/@idNumber=243
/school/students/student[3]/@idNumber=345
/school/fees/@type=teaching
```

You will probably want to trim off some of the parts of the name (i.e. `text()`) etc.

Although it would be much better to stick with processing the XML as is.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nigel Ren it's useful for me now i am storing this key to my table and when i need to fetch the particular value i will search the value from this array. But the problem is that in table i am storing fix value whereas the XML may be dynamic i mean to say if i am stored "/school/students/student/name/firstname/text()" value for firstname but the actual value like /school/students/student[1]/name/firstname/text() means it's added [1] so how can i fetch values from array using this key?